# Netflix app on AppleTV crashes and restarts after beginning to play

Tags: appletv, netflix

I have had this issue for several months, the AppleTV is up-to-date, I've even done a factory reset, but the same problem is happening, and it appears to be most common on Netflix.

After playing for a few minutes, the app crashes and the system restarts. After digging through the menu to get back to whatever was being watched, it usually plays after the point of failure, but sometimes crashes again at a later point.

I think I've ruled out:

1. Out of date software (keeping it up to date, auto updates enabled)
2. App data that is causing a failure (factory reset should fix that)
3. Hardware failure (since it's most common with Netflix)

Last week I turned on the feature to send usage data to Apple so that if a crash report was being generated in the background, it would go to Apple Developers.

Has anyone else had a similar problem? Or does anyone have any ideas about how I can diagnose this problem? I can't find logs anywhere, I feel like I'm working in the dark here,

Comment: Yes I have the same problem! I've checked the same things and my AppleTV still resets while watching Netflix. It's obviously due to one of the updates because I never had any issue until last year or so.

Comment: Are you using photo sharing? if so disable this feature. Sometimes The cached photos freed up so this freezes the streaming function of netflix.

Answer (score 1):

Try reducing the playback setting for Netflix to Medium. This needs to be done through the Netflix web site. Netflix warns this may take up to 8 hours to take effect. Also note it is supposedly profile specific. So make sure you are using the same profile on your Apple TV and for adjusting the setting. Seems to have helped for my frequent crashes.

Comment: Did this fix the problem described?